# Exporting slope raster for entire country in GEE

Tags: dem, google-earth-engine, slope

I have loaded SRTM (30m resolution) DEM data through Google Earth Engine and have determined the slope for the entire country of Peru. 
When I export the image out into Google Drive, I get the following error message- "Export region contains no valid (un-masked) pixels".

How can I export out slope rasters (tifs mostly) via GEE for entire countries? 
My code is available here.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/2f490881ca64a744041c0cc702a24a95

I have also changed the max number of pixels that can be exported, but I still hit the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of exporting a raster of slopes for a country:

```js
// Load the SRTM image.
var srtm = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');

// Calculate slope.
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(srtm);

// Load a country border as a region of interest (roi).
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
var roi = countries.filterMetadata('country_na', 'equals', 'Peru');

// Clip the image to the region of interest.
slope = slope.clip(roi);

// Displaying slope for the region of interest.
var visualization_params = {min: 0, max: 45, palette:'white,red'};
Map.centerObject(roi);
Map.addLayer(slope, visualization_params, "slope");

// Export the image, specifying scale and region.
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: slope.visualize(visualization_params),
  region: roi,
  description: 'imageToDriveExample',
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e12
});
```

Note that:

- If you want to export slope values, rather than a RGB visualization, remove the `.visualize()` method from the export parameters.
- For large regions (such as this) the export will be broken up into a set of tiled GeoTIFF files.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. But unfortunately, the values downloaded seem to not make sense. Slope values (from DEM) are to range between 0-90, after projection to a system with a linear unit. I downloaded loaded the slope tiles from GEE and projected it to a UTm system, using bilinear resampling since slope is continuous. The values range from -665. to 6741, which does not make sense for slope. Any suggestions what this means?

Comment: What code or other program did you use to go "from GEE and projected it to a UTm system"?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of exporting a raster of slope and DEM for a country:

```js
// Load the SRTM image.
var srtm = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003');

// Calculate slope.
var slope = ee.Terrain.slope(srtm);
var elevation = srtm.select('elevation');


// Load a country border as a region of interest (roi).
var countries = ee.FeatureCollection('USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017');
var roi = countries.filterMetadata('country_na', 'equals', 'Madagascar');

// Clip the image to the region of interest.
slope = slope.clip(roi);
var DEM = elevation.clip(roi)

// Displaying slope for the region of interest.
var visualization_slope = {min: 0, max: 45, palette:'white,red'};
Map.centerObject(roi);
Map.addLayer(slope, visualization_slope, "slope");

var visualization_DEM = {min: 0, max: 45, palette:'white,black'};
Map.addLayer(DEM, visualization_DEM, "DEM");

// Export the image
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: slope,
  region: roi,
  description: 'Slope',
  scale: 30,

});


Export.image.toDrive({
image: DEM,
region: roi,
description: 'DEM',
scale: 30,

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the exported worked without any errors after I changed your export command and set the region parameter.

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: slopePeru,
  region: justPeru,
  description: 'slopePeru',
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e12
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For Tyler Erickson answer to work the region parameter of the export command must be changed to:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: slope.visualize(visualization_params),
  region: roi.geometry().bounds(),
  description: 'imageToDriveExample',
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e12
});
```